# How can I specify version of Spring Boot starter dependency using profile maven?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, maven

I'm working in a Spring boot project which has different ways to connect with database, in *dev* I connect with it only with `postgresql` driver, and for *qa* and *prod*, I need connect through `spring-cloud-gcp-starter-sql-postgresql` 'cause we have a cloud environment.

So for manage all this possibilities I'm working with profiles in maven which controls my Spring profiles.

But I have a problem starter dependencies of spring cloud which are placed on my profile declaration 'cause they has no version and maven cannot recognize the default version.

This is a chunk of my pom with the version error:
[image: POM:]

So, how can I solve this problem?

Is there a way to know which is the default version for starter dependencies and save that information in a variable to be used in profile tag?

Any ideas will help a lots.

Thanks for reading and for you time. Greetings to all

Answer (score 0):

You can safely extract `dependencyManagement` out of your profiles.

Reference: [dependency-scope](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html#dependency-scope)

> **import** This scope is only supported on a dependency of type pom in the
> `<dependencyManagement>` section. It indicates the dependency is to be
> replaced with the effective list of dependencies in the specified
> POM's `<dependencyManagement>` section. **Since they are replaced,
> dependencies with a scope of import do not actually participate in
> limiting the transitivity of a dependency.**

So, you can safely extract dependencyManagement out of your profiles.

```
    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>Greenwich.SR2</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>prod</id>
            <activation>
                <activeByDefault>false</activeByDefault>
            </activation>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-cloud-gcp-starter</artifactId>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-cloud-gcp-starter-sql-postgresql</artifactId>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </profile>
        ...
   </profiles>
```

Or you could provide the resolved versions yourself; for `Greenwich.SR2` that will be `1.1.2.RELEASE`...

Comment: How do you know that 1.1.2.RELEASE is the version that I need? is there a way to not put it in hard?

Comment: I can see it in my IDE (IntelliJ), but you could use `mvn dependency:tree`